# How to get the correct values from a multiple where statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a search engine where the user will specify multiple conditions and based on these conditions i will return a datatable.

The problem I am facing is that the conditions are not respected and I am getting wrong results.

I have tried to test every condition alone, it is working, but when I put all the conditions together, I am getting unexpected results.

```
USE [Tenant Management]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RentSearchEngine]
    @sqm INT,
    @category INT,
    @shortRentPrice MONEY,
    @longRentPrice MONEY,
    @fromDate DATETIME,
    @toDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        c.[Name], cate.[Channel Category], tp.type, st.Status, c.Surface,
        g.GOVERNATOR + ' ' + d.District + ' ' + cit.City + ' ' as [Address],
        c.[Short term Price per night] AS [Short term monthly amount],
        c.[Long term price per month] AS [Long term monthly amount],
        c.[Selling Price]
    FROM
        [dbo].[Channel] c
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[Governator] g ON c.[Governator ID] = g.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[District] d ON c.[District ID] = d.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[City] cit ON c.[City ID] = cit.id
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Channel_Category] cate ON c.[Channel Category ID] = cate.ID
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Channel_Type] tp ON c.[Channel Type] = tp.id
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Channel_Status] st ON c.[Channel Status] = st.ID
    LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[Reservations] r ON c.[ID] = r.[Channel ID]
    WHERE 
        c.[Channel Status] = '5'
        AND c.[Channel Type] = '1'
        AND c.[Channel Category ID] = @category OR @category IS NULL
        AND c.Surface BETWEEN @sqm * 0.85 AND @sqm * 1.15 OR @sqm IS NULL
        AND c.[Long term price per month] BETWEEN @longRentPrice * 0.85 
                                              AND @longRentPrice * 1.15 OR @longRentPrice IS NULL
        AND c.[Short term Price per night] BETWEEN @shortRentPrice * 0.85 
                                               AND @shortRentPrice * 1.15 OR @shortRentPrice IS NULL
        AND (r.[Actual Date in] > @fromDate AND r.[Actual Date out] > @toDate)
        AND (r.[Actual Date in] < @fromDate AND r.[Actual Date out] < @toDate)
END
```

The current result is:

```
  fdfd  Residential apatment    For Rent    Available   500  Mont Liban  Baabda  Ain El Remmaneh    1287182.00  28712.00    128712.00
```

When executing the stored procedure as follow:

```
 DECLARE    @return_value int
 EXEC   @return_value = [dbo].[RentSearchEngine]
    @sqm = 40000,
    @category = 1,
    @shortRentPrice = 5,
    @longRentPrice = 4,
    @fromDate = NULL,
    @toDate = NULL
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: What do you mean *"the conditions are not respected"*? I doubt that SQL Server is ignoring your clauses, and it's likely you don't understand how they work. I note in your call you are using `@fromDate = NULL` and `@toDate = NULL`, however, there is no `NULL` handling in your query, so this is very likely the problem. Remember `NULL = NULL` returns `Unknown` and `{Expression} != NULL` returns `Unknown`. This sounds, however, like a catch all query. You have to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` when comparing `NULL` values.

Comment: Have a look at [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [Revisiting Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/). Which explain that the better solution will likely be dynamic SQL or using the `RECOMPILE` option.

Comment: Looks like your `OR`s should take precedence over the `AND`s. But you need to put them in parenthesis for that. E.g. `and c.[Channel Category ID] =@category or @category IS NULL` should read `and (c.[Channel Category ID] =@category or @category IS NULL)`.

Comment: Thank you @stickybit this solved my issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the key issue is the operator preference for AND & OR.
Bear in mind that AND has higher preference than OR. 
In these complex conditions is a good practise to ensure the order with parenthesis.
I will write what I understand you are trying to achieve but ensure you use the parenthesis in the order you require:

```
where c.[Channel Status] = '5'
                and c.[Channel Type] = '1'
                and (c.[Channel Category ID] =@category or @category IS NULL)
                and (c.Surface between @sqm*0.85 and @sqm*1.15 or @sqm IS NULL)
                and (c.[Long term price per month] between @longRentPrice*0.85 and @longRentPrice*1.15 or @longRentPrice IS NULL)
                and (c.[Short term Price per night] between @shortRentPrice*0.85 and @shortRentPrice*1.15 or @shortRentPrice IS NULL)
                and (r.[Actual Date in] > @fromDate and r.[Actual Date out] > @toDate)
                and (r.[Actual Date in] < @fromDate and r.[Actual Date out] < @toDate)
```